# How to pass char** as argument to a thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

How can I pass a `char**` to a thread function?

```
char* myData;
std::thread t(load_frame(&myData));
```

I want to do something like this.

currently, the code does not compile and I get this error

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
```

Comment: `std::thread t(load_frame, &myData);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`std::thread::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) incorrectly.

You can use it as follows (as @ IgorTandetnik has said):

```
char* myData;
std::thread t(load_frame, &myData);
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/oTTs7z)